# Вывести meta title на странице товара opencart 2.х

Tags: php, opencart

По умолчанию у меня в карточке товара opencart 2.x выводится

```
<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
```

$heading_title - это название товара.
А как вывести значения meta title ?

Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В

```
catalog/controller/product/product.php
```

добавьте:

```
$data['meta_title'] = $product_info['meta_title'];
```

после:

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

Вызов в шаблоне:

```
<?php echo $meta_title; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо Большое!